# What is the password for root@localhost's password?

Tags: hadoop, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm configuring the hadoop 2.7.3 on windows ubuntu subsystem. I used `root` as the root account password, but when I try to run /bin/start-yarn.sh, I was required to input the password for root@localhost

```
lizhi@localhost's password:
```

I have tried root for this, but never worked.

I have also tried

```
ssh-genkey 
cat /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

But it still required a password when calling ./start-yarn.sh, what is the password for this, why is it different with root account password?

I've tried to change password to root using passwd, and I still get denied:

```
C:\Users\lizhi>bash
lizhi@LAPTOP-SURFACEP:/mnt/c/Users/lizhi$ sudo su
[sudo] password for lizhi:
root@LAPTOP-SURFACEP:/mnt/c/Users/lizhi# passwd
Enter new UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
passwd: password updated successfully
root@LAPTOP-SURFACEP:/mnt/c/Users/lizhi# ssh localhost
root@localhost's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
root@localhost's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
root@localhost's password:
Received disconnect from 127.0.0.1: 14:
root@LAPTOP-SURFACEP:/mnt/c/Users/lizhi#
```

Welcome for any advise.

Comment: Usually it it blank unless you set it Take a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/171521/what-is-the-password-for-ssh-rootlocalhost)

Comment: @J.Doe, I have tried blank, not work

Comment: Blank as in "", not as in "`blank`". Just hit enter

Comment: You can set up hadoop in windows without the Linux subsystem

Comment: @cricket_007, I want to overcome my linux env.

Comment: @J.Doe still not work, see my trace.

Comment: Still, I'm not sure why you are forcing yourself to use the Linux subsystem within Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is blank (as in "") unless you set it:

`ssh root@localhost` uses the same password for root. It looks like you have not set root password.
To do that log in as root using `sudo -s` then use `passwd` command to set root password.

After that you must be able to ssh as root

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/9017/how-to-know-my-root-password

Comment: Try my answer @PythonNewHand