# What is the password for root@localhost?

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, ssh, installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I´m installing hadoop on WSL(Ubuntu 18) and when I try to connect to ssh localhost the root password is not working.

It´s similar to this issue [What is the password for root@localhost's password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41295225/what-is-the-password-for-rootlocalhosts-password) but the answer there didn´t solved my problem. Still the same output.

```
root@localhost's password:
root@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
```

I´m struggling since hours.

Comment: Referring to that link... Can you detail what happened when you attempted to set your root password? You entered `sudo -s`, entered your normal user password, which then gives you a root shell, then you used `passwd` to set the `root` password? Or did you do something different? Or did you get an error in that process?

Comment: @lurker Everything worked fine. Its just setting the root User Password. When I login to the root user it asks me for the Password which I set before, but the ssh localhost Password seems to be different. I always get the error Permission denied. Try again

Comment: There's a config file for `ssh` that defines what users are allowed to login. Check the `sshd.config`. I'm not sure where it is on Windows 10. It's common, though, to have `root` denied by default for `ssh` access (for obvious security reasons).

Comment: @lurker I couldn´t fix it. I tried many things but it´s not working.